# What is the recommended replacement for LinkedList in Scala 2.11+

Tags: scala

A LinkedList is needed for a custom LRU implementation. When looking at the source we see:

```
@deprecated("Low-level linked lists are deprecated 
   due to idiosyncrasies in interface and incomplete features.", "2.11.0")
class LinkedList[A]() extends AbstractSeq[A]
                     with LinearSeq[A]
                     with GenericTraversableTemplate[A, LinkedList]
                     with LinkedListLike[A, LinkedList[A]]
                     with Serializable {
```

So then what is the recommended alternative (none mentioned here..). Do we fall back to the `java.util.LinkedList`? I am guessing there were a better option ..

**Update**  The specific characteristic of LinkedList that is needed is the ability to access an individual entry on O(1) in order to insert/remove elements in the list efficiently. This would require that a `LinkedListEntry` (or `Node` or similar ..) reference be exposed and returned upon creation of new element in the list.  It appears none of the available implementations - including `java.util.LinkedList` - are suitable.

Comment: `List` is a linked list, and very standard... why not use that?

Comment: @dhg that's true - I forget that scala uses linkedList (instead of ArrayList) as the default. Therefore Vector/IndexedSequence is often better choice for general purpose. I am looking at the List impl now to see if meets my needs.

Comment: @dhg  I am updating the OP to explain why the default ListBuffer will not suit my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably [LinkedHashMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap) may fit better than others, **but:**

there is spray-caching which is a really good implemantation and they are using something called [ConcurrentLinkedHashMap](https://github.com/ben-manes/concurrentlinkedhashmap) which is better for using with Scala as it provides high-performance concurrency.

Comment: LinkedHashMap is not perfect but likely the closest fit provided out of the box. I will award.